# Secugen Hamster pro2o

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, fingerprint, iso-19794

I have **secugen hamster pro20**. I am using asp.net with vb.net to get finger print. I am using SecuGen FDx Pro SDK Activex control to get images. It is working fine and returning to types of data `document.frmmain.objFP[idx].ImageTextData` and `document.frmmain.objFP[idx].MinTextData`. I want data in ISO 19794-2 format. But these both out put does not provide any thing which is related to ISO FOrmat Template LIKE FMR 20.

If any one know how I can get ISO 19794-2 Format template using Secugen FDx Pro SDK Activex control then reply.

Comment: I think you need to tell some more facts about what you have to far as you question is very special.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Since your question is specific to a particular scanner product, you may have better chance of getting answer if you contacted the support team of SDK developers.

Comment: Hi,Please can you tell  me what steps want to follow to run sample html file

Comment: Please can you share how it works to you.For me it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This is code sample which i am using.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK </title>
</head>

<script lang=javascript>
<!--
var aaa = 0;
function fnOpenDevice()
{
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        document.frmmain.objFP[i].DeviceID = document.frmmain.inc.value;
        document.frmmain.objFP[i].CodeName = document.frmmain.dev.value;
        //document.frmmain.objFP[i].MinutiaeMode =              document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
    }

    // template format of objVerify should be the same to those of objFP[]
    //objVerify.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
    return;
}

function fnCapture(idx)
{
document.frmmain.objFP[idx].Capture();
var result = document.frmmain.objFP[idx].ErrorCode;
if (result == 0)
{

    var strimg1 = document.frmmain.objFP[idx].MinTextData;
    document.frmmain.min[idx].value = strimg1;
    //var strmin = document.frmmain.objFP[idx].MinTextData;
    //document.frmmain.min[idx].value = strmin;
}
else
    alert('failed - ' + result);

return;
}

function fnRegister()
{
var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;

if ( objVerify.RegisterForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0    )
    alert('success- registered');
else
    alert('failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

return;
```

}

```
function fnVerifyEx()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;
    var strmin3 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyExForText(strmin1, strmin2, strmin3) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0)
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnVerify()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnSetimage()
{
    document.frmmain.objFP.ImageTextData = document.frmmain.img1.value;

    return;
}
// -->

</script>

<body>
```

**ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK**

```
<OBJECT id=objVerify style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" height=0 width=0 
    classid="CLSID:8D613732-7D38-4664-A8B7-A24049B96117" 
    name=objVerify VIEWASTEXT>
</OBJECT>

<form name=frmmain>

Device Type :
<select name=dev>
<option value=0>FDP02
<option value=1>FDU02
<option value=2>FDU03
<option value=3>FDU04
<option selected value=4>FDU05

</select>

Instance No. :
<select name=inc>
<option value=-1>-1 
<option value=0>0
<option value=1>1
<option value=2>2
<option value=3>3
<option value=4>4
<option value=5>5
<option value=6>6
<option value=7>7
<option value=8>8
<option value=9>9
</select>

<p>
Template Format:
<select name=templateFormat>
<option value=256>ANSI 378
<option value=512>SG 400
<option value=768>ISO 19794-2
</select>

<input type=button name=open value='Open Device' OnClick='fnOpenDevice();'>
<p>

<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<caption> Fingerprint Images </caption>
<tr>
```

```
<p>
```

min1 : 
   min2 : 
   min3 :

```
</BODY>
 </HTML>
```